# What properties does this set satisfy?

Tags: general-topology

> $S\subset \Bbb{R}^2$ be defined by $$S=\{\Big(m+\frac{1}{4^{|p|}},n+\frac{1}{4^{|q|}}\Big): m,n,p,q \in \Bbb{Z}\}$$
>   I need to answer whether it is discrete or not, what are the limit points and is $S^c$ it path connected.

Each point is at positive distance point from the other points, thus every point is isolated therefore the set is discrete.

Set of limit points will be $S'=\{\Big(m,n+\frac{1}{4^{|q|}}\Big): m,n,q \in \Bbb{Z}\}\cup \{\Big(m+\frac{1}{4^{|p|}},n\Big): m,n,p \in \Bbb{Z}\}\cup\{(m,n): m,n \in \Bbb{Z}\}$

And intuitively I feel that $S^c$ should be polygonally connected which implies path connected.

Comment: yeah I've mentioned that

Comment: Sorry, I've missed it.

Comment: $S$ has limit points which are contained in it, so it cannot be discrete. That each point is at positive distance from the other points is always true in a metric space and not that much related to discreteness.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch How are limit points contained in $S$?

Comment: For example $(m,n) = (m - 1 + \frac{1}{4^0}, n - 1 + \frac{1}{4^0}) \in S$ is a limit point of $S$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ as you already noticed. It works similarly for the other limit points you found.